# Defining MessageSource and LocaleResolver beans in Spring MVC for adding i18n support

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm trying to add i18n support to a Spring MVC project(3.2.0.RELEASE). I have two bundles below /src/main/resources/bundle:

```
messageBundle_en.properties
messageBundle_vi.properties
```

And the configurations for spring mvc as below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="false" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:bundle/messageBundle" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="vi" />
</bean>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

with above configurations the application is not working. The error was

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'message.home.header.welcome' for locale 'en_US'.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
```

I spent many hours comparing with tutorials of adding i18n support. I saw that there is only one difference: bean definitions of `CookieLocaleResolver` and `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` have id attributes. So I changed the configurations to

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:bundle/messageBundle" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="vi" />
</bean>
```

Now it's working well!

Do `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and `CookieLocaleResolver` require to have ids in their definitions?

Why doesn't `InternalResourceViewResolver` need an id?

Wondering if anyone can give me an explanation in details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DispatcherServlet.java

```
public static final String LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME = "localeResolver";

private void initLocaleResolver(ApplicationContext context) {
    try {
        this.localeResolver = context.getBean(LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME, LocaleResolver.class);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Using LocaleResolver [" + this.localeResolver + "]");
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        // We need to use the default.
        this.localeResolver = getDefaultStrategy(context, LocaleResolver.class);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name '" + LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME +
                    "': using default [" + this.localeResolver + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Spring uses some conventional bean name to intialize DispatcherServlet.

In your case, spring will use a default one if no bean named "localeResolver" is found (therefore your custom LocaleResover is ignored).

UPDATE

In messageSource case,

> "When  an  ApplicationContext  is  loaded,  it  automatically 
>   searches  for  a  MessageSource  bean defined in the context. **The
>   bean must have the name messageSource**. If such a bean is found, all
>   calls to the preceding methods are delegated to the message source. If
>   no message source is found, the ApplicationContext attempts to find a
>   parent containing a bean with the same name. If it does, it uses that
>   bean as the MessageSource. If the ApplicationContext cannot find any
>   source for messages, an empty DelegatingMessageSource is instantiated
>   in order to be able to accept calls to the methods defined above."

quoted from spring doc.

Comment: The same counts for messageSource. Spring fetches it by name.

Comment: `messageSource` is initialized in `AbstractApplicationContext.java`