# Spring MVC Messages is OK in JSP but not in my Java code

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a problem recently using spring mvc.
I am using i18n messages in my project. but I found jsp is ok, but does work in my custom java code.

my config as as follow：

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    abstract="false" scope="singleton" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="basename" value="messages/messages" />
</bean>
```

my jsp code(I just write this testing code, it gets the result):

```
<spring:message code="error.user.none.registered" arguments="aaa"/>
```

my java code:

```
@Resource
protected MessageSource messageSource;
public Object login(String email, String password, String ip)
            throws Exception {
        User t = userDao.queryByEmail(email);
        if (t == null) { // 账号不存在
            return messageSource.getMessage(
                    Constants.ERROR_USER_NONE_REGISTERED,
                    new Object[] { email }, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
        }
.....
}
```

this code is in my UserService.java login method, I want to check the email is registered. but also get errors

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'error.user.none.registered' for locale 'zh_CN'.
```

Comment: From your code, I guess that your message source isn't correctly retrieved. I haven't used @Resource before... I think you can try Autowire protected MessageSource messageSource instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you define "messageSource" in your dispatcher-servlet.xml?

I guess your java code (a service I presume) is defined in applicationContext.xml so that it is not injected with the messageSource expected.

Comment: you mean I need to import the other config fils which I defined service interface?

Comment: @風一樣的男子 Please refer to this for detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909598/defining-messagesource-and-localeresolver-beans-in-spring-mvc-for-adding-i18n-su/17915856#17915856. Nice username by the way.